# How do I structure a "sphinx" documentation git repo to document other repos as submodules?

Tags: python, git, python-sphinx, git-submodules

I have multiple git repos that make up a larger library.

I want to create a "sphinx" documentation repo that references the other repos as submodules, and build the documentation in the "sphinx" repo. The sphinx repo documentation tree will be published as the documentation for the larger library. It will be regenerated whenever any of the constituent repos are updated.

I'm also using the autodoc and napoleon extensions.

I have a shell script that walks through the submodules running sphinx-apidoc, then runs make html in the top directory:

```
SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS='members,undoc-members,inherited-members,show-inheritance'

for dir in `find * -type d | egrep -v "(^_)|(^\.)"`; do
    sphinx-apidoc -f -e -a -o _build/docs/${dir} ${dir};
done

make html
```

The top level index.rst file:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :caption: Contents:

   _build/docs/module1/modules.rst
   _build/docs/module2/modules.rst
```

(The submodules don't have index.rst files.)

The submodules only get linked in shallowly, so class folders in a submodule don't show up. I've tried variations, but each one is flawed in a different way.

Does someone have a simple example how to put this together? Surely I'm missing something fundamental?

**Update**: Added screenshot of first page.

Requirement: Create a Sphinx "project" folder, including any build scripts and index.rst files, with softlinks to local git project folders, so that all of the documentation of all linked projects can be stitched together automatically in one place? The built documentation folder can then be published, such as to AWS S3, as part of the automated build flow.

[image: Current first page]

Comment: Requirement is not clear. Can you put a snapshot of generated HTML?

Comment: Why would the generated HTML clarify the requirements? But sure.

Comment: Have you found out how to do that by now?

Comment: @mpariente No. And shortly after posting that, I changed jobs, and haven't followed up.